# how to use argparse inside a class in python

Tags: argparse

I'm trying to use argparse inside class. But I'm confused and I'm getting the below error. How to fix this.?

```
import argparse
import paramiko
class add():
   def __init__(self):
      pass

   def execute_remote_command(self,Host, Port, User_name, Pwd, Cmd):
       ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
       ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
       ssh.connect(Host, Port, User_name, Pwd, Cmd)

       stdin,stdout,stderr=ssh.exec_command(Cmd)
       outlines = stdout.readlines()
       resp = ''.join(outlines)
       ans = str(resp)
       print(ans)

obj = add()
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Pinging a server')
parser.add_argument('-host','--Host',dest = 'Host',help='IP of server')
parser.add_argument('-port','--Port',dest = 'Port',help='Port of server')
parser.add_argument('-username','--User_name',dest 
='User_name',help='User_name)
parser.add_argument('-pwd','--Pwd',dest = 'Pwd',help='Pwd of server')
parser.add_argument('-cmd','--Cmd',dest = 'Cmd',help='Cmd of server')
args = parser.parse_args()


obj.execute_remote_command(args.Host, args.Port, args.User_name, args.Pwd, args.Cmd)
```

Comment: I cleaned up the indentation (I think), but still don't see an error message.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding some code so you could launch this from your console:

```
 # This inside file add.py

if __name__ == "__main__":
    obj = add()
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Pinging a server')
    parser.add_argument('-host','--Host',dest = 'Host',help='IP of server')
    parser.add_argument('-port','--Port',dest = 'Port',help='Port of server')
    parser.add_argument('-username','--User_name',des='User_name',help='User_name)
    parser.add_argument('-pwd','--Pwd',dest = 'Pwd',help='Pwd of server')
    parser.add_argument('-cmd','--Cmd',dest = 'Cmd',help='Cmd of server')

    args = parser.parse_args()

    obj.execute_remote_command(args.Host, args.Port, args.User_name, args.Pwd, args.Cmd)
```

Then you can launch this like this:

```
python add.py --Host your-host --Port your-port --User_name your-name --Pwd your-pwd --Cmd your-cmd
```

There is no reason why this should not work.
Also consider creating just a function `execute_remote_command`. You are not using any state in your class, which makes it quite useless.